# How to call a function in R which I specify via the commandline?

Tags: r

How do I do this in `R`:

I have sourced a function with some name `exampleFoo` suppose:

`exampleFoo <- function(a, predefined, signature)`

Given the character vector `exampleFoo`, how can I use that to call the function with that name?

Comment: I propose you spend more time clarifying your need. You want to call R from, say, bash with an argument that can be read in and used to call the like-named function?

Comment: Yes...I have simplified my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if this is going on inside another function or at the top level. I'll take those in reverse order.

```
exampleFoo <- function(a, predefined, signature) {
   1:10
}

FUN <- "exampleFoo"

get(FUN)
get(FUN)()

> get(FUN)
function(a, predefined, signature) {
   1:10
}
> get(FUN)()
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

In a function, the `match.fun` argument is most applicable here. `get` looks for objects with the name supplied to it, whereas `match.fun` only considers function objects when searching. This has the additional benefit then of not matching non-function objects that may have the same name.

```
FOO <- function(f) {
  BAR <- match.fun(f)
  BAR()
}

> FOO(FUN)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> FOO("exampleFoo")
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

You can't use `match.fun` (easily?) at the top level as it is designed to perform matching in the parent frame of the caller and the Global environment doesn't have a parent (IIRC).

### Other Examples

@agstudy suggests a `switch` based approach to having a wrapper function that can call one of several pre-defined functions by name. In the comments there I proposed two simpler alternatives. Here I expand upon that:

```
foo1 <- function(method, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  FUN <- match.fun(method)
  do.call(FUN, dots)
}
```

or

```
foo2 <- function(method = c("fun1", "fun2", "fun3"), ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  method <- match.arg(method)
  FUN <- match.fun(method)
  do.call(FUN, dots)
}
```

I've written these as pretty general functions which take any arguments plus `method`. If the functions reference by / passed to `method` have a `...` argument, then these could be called directly, perhaps with one or more named arguments, e.g.

```
## assuming `method` refers to a function with a first argument `x` and also
##   a `...` argument
foo3 <- function(method, x, ...) {
  FUN <- match.fun(method)
  FUN(x, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text<-"exampleFoo"
exampleFoo<-function(x) print("Success")
eval(parse(text=paste(text,"()")))
#[1] "Success"
```

As @joran suggested, `get()` seems to work as a replacement for `eval(parse(text="..."))`

```
get(text)()
#[1] "Success"
```

Comment: Thomas Lumley coined one of the older foRtunes in the **fortunes** package: "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question." `get()` and `match.fun()` are obvious choices here depending on in what way the OP wants to be finding and using the named function.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `switch` for this, something like :

```
algoFactory <- function (method = c("algo1", "alog2", 
                                   "algo3")
{
  method = method[1]
  switch(method, algo1 = {
  res = algo1.Impl(...)
}, algo2 = {
  res = algo2.Impl(...)
}, algo3 = {
  res = algo3.Impl(...)
})}
```

And each time I add a new algorithm I update this main function. In your RscripT , you call it for example:

```
 Rscript  algoFactory.R 'algo1'
```

Comment: That is very inefficient in terms of having to have a separate clause in the `switch` for each new algorithm. You could rewrite that as a single call to `match.fun` and then a call to that matched function. Or if you wanted to limit the number of algorithms, keep the `method` argument and options, `match.arg()` on `method` in the function, then `match.fun` on that output, then call the matched function - 3 lines.

Comment: Also, I think there is another infelicity there. `method = method[1]` should really be `method <- match.arg(method)`. As you have it now, `method` could actually be passed anything and it would try to match that against the options in `switch`. Using `match.arg` automatically gets you a check that `method` comes from one of the stated alternatives.

Comment: @GavinSimpson completely agree for the `match.arg(method)` use.(no need to edit my answer since you brilliantly expose it in your answer)   But I still think that the `switch` here is more readable than `match.fun`. Also, When I wrote it I have in head to write all the algorithms inside the algoFactory function.